How to make active menu item background more visible
How to make this active menu item background blue or darker like in Windows desktop applications menus?

Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu is created using this code
(also in JSFiddle):


<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Action
      </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
    <li>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">S<u>e</u>parated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




You want it to have a different color when it hover. You need to write a style for this. So you can give the color you want here. The code below explains how to change the color of the elements. You can choose the color you want to add.
<style>
      .dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
        background-color: blue !important;
        color:white !important;
      }      
  </style>

Demo


.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: blue !important;
            color:white !important;
          } 
<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Action
      </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
    <li>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">S<u>e</u>parated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




This does not change background if up and down arrow keys are used for navigation. There is no such state so it is not possible in css. Using :active state changes background for all items. How to change backgruond if arrows keys are used for navigation?

I added the function when hover with the mouse. Now I am adding the up and down(focus) function. You can edit it as you wish.

I added white for color and !important for force.
